# SwiftUI: Switch .sheet on enum, does not work

Tags: swiftui

I have two Modal/Popover `.sheet`'s I would like to show based on which button is pressed by a user. I have setup an `enum` with the different choices and set a default choice.

***Expected behaviour:***

When the user selects any choice, the right sheet is displayed. When the user THEN selects the other choice, it also shows the correct sheet.

***Observed behaviour:***

In the example below, when the user ***first picks the second choice***, the first sheet is shown and will continue to show until the user selects the first sheet, then it will start to switch.

Debug printing shows that the `@State` variable is changing, however, the sheet presentation does not observe this change and shows the sheets as described above. Any thoughts?

```
import SwiftUI


//MARK: main view:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    //construct enum to decide which sheet to present:
    enum ActiveSheet {
        case sheetA, sheetB
    }
    
    //setup needed vars and set default sheet to show:
    @State var activeSheet = ActiveSheet.sheetA //sets default sheet to Sheet A
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            
            Button(action: {
                self.activeSheet = .sheetA //set choice to Sheet A on button press
                print(self.activeSheet) //debug print current activeSheet value
                self.showSheet.toggle() //trigger sheet
            }) {
                Text("Show Sheet A")
            }
            
            
            Button(action: {
                self.activeSheet = .sheetB //set choice to Sheet B on button press
                print(self.activeSheet) //debug print current activeSheet value
                self.showSheet.toggle() //trigger sheet
            }) {
                Text("Show Sheet B")
            }
        }
        
        //sheet choosing view to display based on selected enum value:
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            switch self.activeSheet {
            case .sheetA:
                SheetA() //present sheet A
            case .sheetB:
                SheetB() //present sheet B
            }
        }
    }
}





//MARK: ancillary sheets:
struct SheetA: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am sheet A")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct SheetB: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am sheet B")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With some very small alterations to your code, you can use `sheet(item:)` for this, which prevents this problem:

```
//MARK: main view:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    //construct enum to decide which sheet to present:
    enum ActiveSheet : String, Identifiable { // <--- note that it's now Identifiable
        case sheetA, sheetB
        var id: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
    
    @State var activeSheet : ActiveSheet? = nil // <--- now an optional property
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            
            Button(action: {
                self.activeSheet = .sheetA
            }) {
                Text("Show Sheet A")
            }
            
            
            Button(action: {
                self.activeSheet = .sheetB 
            }) {
                Text("Show Sheet B")
            }
        }
        //sheet choosing view to display based on selected enum value:
        .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { sheet in // <--- sheet is of type ActiveSheet and lets you present the appropriate sheet based on which is active
            switch sheet {
            case .sheetA:
                SheetA() 
            case .sheetB:
                SheetB()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that without using `item:`, current versions of SwiftUI render the initial sheet with the first state value (ie sheet A in this case) and don't update properly on the first presentation. Using this `item:` approach solves the issue.

Comment: Alternatively, you could capture the state variable `activeSheet `, e.g. `.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { [activeSheet] in ...}

Comment: Good trick -- hadn't run across that before.

Comment: Dint forget onDismiss action. .sheet(item: $activeSheet, onDismiss: { activeSheet = nil }) { sheet in

Comment: That’s handled by the system automatically