# Share Sheet does not open from the first

Tags: swift, swiftui

**The set in the section structure includes headers and images to share. But there is a problem, the sharing window opens only a few times. What could be the problem?**

```
@State var items : [Any] = []
    @State var sheet = false
    var section: Sections
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(section.title).font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold)).frame(width: 247, height: 44, alignment: .topLeading).offset(x: 0.0, y: 5)
                Button(action: {
                    items.removeAll()
                    items.append(UIImage(named: section.card)!)
                    sheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image("send").frame(width: 36, height: 14, alignment: .top).offset(x: 0.0, y: -8)
                }

            }.sheet(isPresented: $sheet, content: {
                ShareSheet(items: items)



struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var items : [Any]
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your title says "does not open from the first" and the question says "opens only a few times" -- what exactly is happening?

Comment: You can try. This curtain displays the insides Share (send to someone) only if you press it once, then close it and open it again.

Comment: Actually, I can't try it -- you haven't included all the necessary code to run your example. Running my own variation of yours, the sheet appears every time for me.

Comment: Sheet itself opens every time, and content inside only from the second. https://imgur.com/cubzTQA

Comment: Ah -- I know what that is. You haven't included `Sections` or `items` in your code, so I can't modify yours to show you the answer, but it relates to an issue in iOS 14 using `sheet(isPresented:)` vs `sheet(item:)`. See this answer of mine on the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work/66162319#66162319 If you update your code with enough code to run, I can show you the answer specifically for your case.

Comment: Thanks. You've been very helpful))

Comment: I did everything as it was written but now this [ShareSheet] connection invalid has appeared

Answer (score 0):

Define the items variable in the ShareSheet as Binding because it gets the value from View.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
        @Binding var items : [Any]
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
            
            let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
            
            return controller
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
            
        }
    }
```

And pass the binding value from View.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items : [Any] = []
    @State var sheet = false
    var section: Sections
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(section.title).font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold)).frame(width: 247, height: 44, alignment: .topLeading).offset(x: 0.0, y: 5)
                Button(action: {
                    items.removeAll()
                    items.append(UIImage(named: section.card)!)
                    sheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image("send").frame(width: 36, height: 14, alignment: .top).offset(x: 0.0, y: -8)
                }

            }.sheet(isPresented: $sheet, content: {
                ShareSheet(items: $items)
}
}
```