# State does not get updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem with a `@State` not updating its value and I do not understand what is causing this issue. If you can explain the reason of the following code and behaviour I would greatly appreciate it.

I have th following UI class:

```
struct CardGrid: View {
    
    private static let portraitViewColumns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
    
    var cards: [Card]
    
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var showDetails = false
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: CardGrid.portraitViewColumns) {
            ForEach(cards) { card in
                Button {
                    // the line of code in question
                    selectedIndex = cards.index(matching: card)!
                    showDetails = true
                } label: {
                    UICard(card: card)

                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails)  {
            CardDetailView(cards: cards, index: selectedIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

and an extension which is called in the marked line above:

```
extension Collection where Element: Identifiable {
    func index(matching element: Element) -> Self.Index? {
        firstIndex(where: { $0.id == element.id })
    }
}
```

That `CardGrid` has an array of `Card` objects. For each object a button is created in a `VGrid`. If a button is clicked a detail view opens as sheet, displaying details about the card associated with the button. Because the detail view allows paging between `Card` objects of the array of cards, it is called with the array of cards itself and an index of the card to initialise the view with. This is done in the commented line by finding the index of the card that was tapped/clicked on within the array of cards.

**Expected Behaviour**
Given an array of cards with `[Card 1, Card 2, Card 3]` it is expected that if the user taps on the button for `Card 2` the `func index(matching element: Element) -> Self.Index?`method returns the index 1 and the card detail view opens up displaying details for `Card 1`.

**Observed Behaviour**
Method `func index(matching element: Element) -> Self.Index?` returns index 1 but the state `selectedIndex` does not update to 1 but remains at 0. The card detail view shows up, displaying details about `Card 1`. The same is true if the user taps on the button for `Card 3`.
This behaviour will persist until the user taps on the button for `Card 1`, displaying the card details for `Card 1`. Closing the detail view sheet and the tap on the button for `Card 2` will now set the `selectedIndex` to 1 and open the detail view for `Card 2` correctly as was expected.

I do not understand what causes the state not to update and why I starts updating once the user invokes the card detail view for the first element of the `cards` array.

Comment: You haven't included the necessary code to get this to compile (we'd need to see `Card` and `CardGrid`), but the problem is almost certainly that you're using `sheet(isPresented:)` which calculates its content on first render and `sheet(item:)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162319/560942

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I cannot mark jnpdx's comment as answer because that is exactly what caused the problem.

I was able to resolve the issue by refactoring the code to this:

```
struct CardGrid: View {
    
    private static let portraitViewColumns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
    
    var cards: [Card]
    
    // stored the selected card in a state
    @State private var selectedCard: Card? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: CardGrid.portraitViewColumns) {
            ForEach(cards) { card in
                Button {
                    selectedCard = card
                } label: {
                    UICard(card: card)

                }
            }
        }
        // use the sheet(item) method instead and calculate the index in it
        .sheet(item: $selectedCard) { c in
            CardDetailView(cards: cards, index: cards.index(matching: c)!)
        }
    }
}
``
```