# SwiftUI List scrolls to the top on tapping to view sheet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a `List` in my `View` that has an `onTapGesture` on each of the items in the list that is set to display a `sheet` of a separate `View` and passes selected object into it to display more information.

The information gets passed in but every time I tap on an item in the list it will display the `sheet` but scroll all the way back to the top of the `List`, does anyone know if there's a fix for this or if its just a bug?

Code Below:

```
@State var selectedItem: Item = Item()
@State var showPopup = false

var body: some View {

  VStack{
            List(items, id: \.self) {item in
                ItemCard(Item: item)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture(){
                        self.selectedItem = item
                        self.showPopup = true
                    }
            }.id(UUID())
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showPopup) {ItemDetails(i:selectedItem)}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but I'd suggest you look into `sheet(item:)` rather than `sheet(isPresented:)` -- the latter tends to have issues with displaying the last selected item sometimes. The former will guarantee the sheet information is up-to-date. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work/66162319#66162319 for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign a new `id` to your `List` on every single render (like you do when you do `.id(UUID())`), SwiftUI considers it a completely new `View`. So, when you change your `@State` by tapping an item, SwiftUI thinks a new `List` is created and scrolls to the top.

Remove `.id(UUID())` to fix this.