# Unexpected SwiftUI @State behavior

Tags: swiftui, state

**The setup:**

My app has a View `ToolBar` (all shortened):

```
struct ToolBar: View {
    @State private var ownerShare: CKShare?
    @State private var show_ownerModifyShare = false
// …
```

The toolbar has some buttons that are created by functions. One of them is

```
func sharingButton(imageName: String, enabled: Bool) -> SharingButton {
    return SharingButton(systemImageName: imageName, enabled: enabled) {
        Task {
            do {
                (_, participantShare, ownerShare) = try await dataSource.getSharingInfo()
                // …
                if ownerShare != nil { show_ownerModifyShare = true }
            } catch (let error) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the body:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // …
            sharingButton(imageName: "square.and.arrow.up", enabled: currentMode == .displayingItems)
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $show_ownerModifyShare) {
                    // A CKShare record exists in the iCloud private database. Present a controller that allows to modify it.
                    CloudSharingView(container: CKContainer(identifier: kICloudContainerID), shareRecord: ownerShare!, dataSource: dataSource)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

When the `sharingButton` is tapped, `ownerShare` is set in `Task {…}`, since the iCloud database is shared as an owner.
Accordingly, `show_ownerModifyShare = true` is executed, and thus the body of `struct ToolBar` is newly rendered.
However, `CloudSharingView(container: CKContainer(identifier: kICloudContainerID), shareRecord: ownerShare!, dataSource: dataSource)` crashes, because `ownerShare` is `nil`, although it is only set `true` after `ownerShare` has been set `!= nil`.

**My question:**

What could be the reason, and how to correct the code?

**EDIT:** (due to the comment of jnpdx):

I replaced `.fullScreenCover(isPresented:` by

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $ownerShare) { _ in
  CloudSharingView(container: CKContainer(identifier: kICloudContainerID), shareRecord: ownerShare!, dataSource: dataSource)
}
```

but the code still crashes with `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when `ownerShare!` is used.

Comment: Use item `item` form of `fullScreenCover` rather than `isPresented` and pass in `shareRecord` as the item

Comment: @jnpdx Interesting! Will try...

Comment: In your update, you didn't actually use the `item`. You should be using the parameter it sends the closure (not ignoring it as `_`). That's what you should pass to `shareRecord`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the problem. Maybe you can write a short answer so that I can accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `item` form of `fullScreenCover`, which allows you to send a dynamically-changed parameter to the inner closure:

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $ownerShare) { share in
  CloudSharingView(container: CKContainer(identifier: kICloudContainerID), shareRecord: share, dataSource: dataSource)
}
```

This is a common issue with `sheet` and the related functions in SwiftUI, which calculate their closures when first rendered and not at presentation time. See related:

- [SwiftUI: Switch .sheet on enum, does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work)