# @State is not updating when using popover

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this `List` view

```
List(expenses) { expense in
    ExpenseListItemView(expense: expense)
        .swipeActions {
            Button("Edit") {
                selectedExpenseId = expense.id
                showAddExpensePopup = true
            }.tint(.blue)
        }
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $showExpenseEditorPopup) {
        if let id = selectedExpenseId {
            ExpenseEditorScreen(expenseId: id)
        } else {
            ExpenseEditorScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

`selectedExpenseId` and `showAddExpensePopup` are both `@State` variables and `selectedExpenseId` is not getting updated and so I am always in the else case in the popover and can't edit an existing object

I know I can achieve this functionality by using the other `.popover(item: )`, I just want to understand what's happening in this case

Comment: Use `popover(item:)` or use `.popover(isPresented: $showExpenseEditorPopup) { [selectedExpenseId] in`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work for example

Comment: "I just want to understand what's happening in this case" -- the content of the closure is evaluated before `selectedExpenseId` changes

Answer (score 2):

It's because you didn't get the `@State` in `body` so SwiftUI's dependency tracking didn't think you care about it (It only calls `body` when states are set if you use also the getter). One way to call the getter is in the closure capture list, e.g.

```
 .popover(isPresented: $showExpenseEditorPopup) { [selectedExpenseId] in
        if let id = selectedExpenseId {
```

Learn the details in Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020 at 7:32.