# Variables are updated on the wrong order Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am doing an app that lists some photos. When the user taps a photo, a sheet appears with the selected photo.

The problem is: Sometimes I tap on the second photo, i. e., index = 1, and the first photo appears on the Sheet View. I don't know why, but the problem should also happen with other indices but until now only with the second photo. Here is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
   
   @Binding var photo: String
   
   var body: some View {
       Text("photo title: " + photo)
   }
}


struct ContentView: View {
   
   @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
   @State private var photoEdition: Bool = false
   
   @State var photos: [String] = ["gigio", "lulu", "lucky"]
   
   private var photoToEdit: Binding<String> {
       
       .init(get: { () -> String in
           print("get", photos[selectedIndex], selectedIndex)
           return photos[selectedIndex]
       },
             set: { (newValue) in
           photos[selectedIndex] = newValue
           print("set", photos[selectedIndex], selectedIndex)
       })
   }
   
   var body: some View {
       
       VStack {
           ForEach(photos.indices, id:\.self) { index in
               Button(action: {
                   photoTapHandler(selectedIndex: index)
               }) {
                   Text(photos[index]).padding(10)
               }
           }
           
       } .sheet(isPresented: $photoEdition, content: {
           SheetView(photo: photoToEdit)
       })
   }
   
   private func photoTapHandler(selectedIndex: Int) {
       print("updating selected index to ", selectedIndex)
       self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
       self.photoEdition = true
   }
}
```

I think what is happening is that on the `photoTapHandler` function, the variable `photoEdition` is set to true before `selectedIndex` is changed. Any idea why? Here is the execution logs.

```
updating selected index to  1
get gigio 0
get gigio 0
```

By replacing the body with the following, I don't get the error.

```swift
var body: some View {
        
    VStack {
        ForEach(photos.indices, id:\.self) { index in
            Button(action: {
                photoTapHandler(selectedIndex: index)
            }) {
                Text(photos[index]).padding(10)
            }
        }
            
    }.onChange(of: selectedIndex) { selectedIndex in
        self.photoEdition = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $photoEdition, content: {
            SheetView(photo: photoToEdit)
    })
}

private func photoTapHandler(selectedIndex: Int) {
    print("updating selected index to ", selectedIndex)
    self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
    // self.photoEdition = true
}
```

Thank you all in advance! :)

Comment: You should use item instead of isPresented or capture the variable in the closure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work

Comment: Indicies are considered unsafe when dealing with SwiftUI

Comment: isn't this a race condition?

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI is declarative so Order of Operations is a bit different. Just because an operation comes first doesn't mean it will be executed first.

In this case, when you tap a photo, you expect `selectedIndex` to be updated ***before*** `photoEdition`. But there's a possibility that the state changes (of which there are two) might execute asynchronously and in different orders. So when photoEdition == true Swift UI will re-render sheet view and photoToEdit could still still be in the middle of its operation of returing the old selectedIndex. Hence wrong photo.

Below `photoEdition` is ***only*** updated when `selectedIndex` has **definitely** been updated. The `onChange` modifier ensures that the `photoEdition` is **only** updated after `selectedIndex` has been updated. This isn't the cureall for race conditions but it works in this instance. Below this I provide a Swiftier answer.

```
var body: some View {
        
    VStack {
        ForEach(photos.indices, id:\.self) { index in
            Button(action: {
                photoTapHandler(selectedIndex: index)
            }) {
                Text(photos[index]).padding(10)
            }
        }
            
    }.onChange(of: selectedIndex) { selectedIndex in
        self.photoEdition = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $photoEdition, content: {
            SheetView(photo: photoToEdit)
    })
}

private func photoTapHandler(selectedIndex: Int) {
    print("updating selected index to ", selectedIndex)
    self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
    // self.photoEdition = true
}
```

This is a more "Swifty" way to do things IMO.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var photo: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("photo title: " + photo)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    struct Photo: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
    }
    
    @State var photos: [Photo] = [Photo(id: 0, name: "gigio"), Photo(id: 1, name: "lulu"), Photo(id: 2, name: "lucky")]
    @State var selectedPhoto: Photo? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(photos) { photo in
                Button(action: {
                    selectedPhoto = photo
                }) {
                    Text(photo.name).padding(10)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedPhoto) { photo in
            SheetView(photo: $selectedPhoto.name)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first option solves my problem. The second, I agree that is more elegant, but it doesn't fit my needs. It I want to edit the photo on the sheet and update the list I would have to run over the photos array every time searching for the index and update the value of the array for example.

Comment: Understood! I like giving options so hopefully I didn't offend...

Comment: You didn't! Thank you!