# Displaying Received JSON Data in JSONResponseView Shows Empty Object

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a feature that involves sending a JSON request and then receiving a JSON response. However, I'm facing an issue while trying to display the received JSON data on a subsequent view, specifically the `JSONResponseView`.

The problem I'm encountering is that when I navigate to the `JSONResponseView`, I'm only seeing an empty JSON object displayed there `[:]`. This is perplexing to me because I can confirm from the console logs that I am indeed receiving a valid JSON response.

To give you a bit more context, I have a process in place where I make the JSON request, receive a JSON response, and then attempt to present the `JSONResponseView` with the received JSON data. However, even though I'm triggering the JSONResponseView presentation after receiving the response, the view seems to display an empty JSON object.

Is there a possibility of a delay in receiving the JSON response. I've verified that the timing of when I trigger the JSONResponseView and when the response arrives is nearly instantaneous, down to the millisecond level.

Why might I be encountering this behavior? How can I properly pass and display the received JSON data on the `JSONResponseView`?

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        PersonDetailsSection(name: $person1Name, title: "Enter Person 1's Details")
        
        Button {
            if let jsonData = JSONPayloadGenerator.createPayload(person1Name: person1Name) {
                sendRequest(with: jsonData)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("My App")
    .padding()
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingResponseView) {
        JSONResponseView(jsonResponse: responseJSON)
    .onAppear {
        print("Presenting JSONResponseView")
    }
}

func sendRequest(with jsonData: Data) {
    // Create the URL
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:7071/api") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    
    // Make the request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error:", error)
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("No data received")
            return
        }
        
        // Print the raw JSON data received from the server
        if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("-->Raw JSON Data Received:", jsonString)
        }
        
        do {
            let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            print(" Report:", result ?? "No result")
            
            // Update the responseJSON state with the received JSON data
            responseJSON = result ?? ["Test": "OK"]
            
            // Present the JSONResponseView
            showingResponseView = true
        } catch {
            print("Error parsing JSON:", error)
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
    
    // Print the JSON payload
    if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Generated JSON Payload Outgoing:\n", jsonString)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` or change `.sheet(isPresented: $showingResponseView) {` to `.sheet(isPresented: $showingResponseView) { [responseJSON] in` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work

Comment: You do not update your state var in main queue.

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx. 
`.sheet(isPresented: $showingResponseView) { [responseJSON] in
                    JSONResponseView(jsonResponse: responseJSON)` has worked.

Comment: Great -- please consider upvoting the answer I linked to if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jnpdx, the code is working now.

I have changed:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingResponseView) {
    if showingResponseView {
        JSONResponseView(jsonResponse: responseJSON)
    }
}
```

to

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingResponseView) { [responseJSON] in
    JSONResponseView(jsonResponse: responseJSON)
}
```