# fullScreenCover not updating data for the content view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

```
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.showEditRoom) {
        EditRoomView(someData: someData, selectedRoom: $viewModel.selectedRoom)
    }
```

I have a `fullScreenCover` modifier that presents a view when a certain condition is met. The view that is presented, `EditRoomView`, takes a few parameters including `selectedRoom`, a binding property.

The issue I'm encountering is that when the `EditRoomView` is presented using `fullScreenCover`, it doesn't reflect the latest value of the `viewModel.selectedRoom` property. I update this property when a row is selected, and then I present the `EditRoomView`.

I attempted to use the `fullScreenCover(item:`  but with this approach, I encountered issues in binding a variable since `selectedRoom` is a `Binding` property in the next view. Additionally, the view becomes unresponsive after its initial appearance.

Comment: Use `item:` instead of `isPresented:`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work

Comment: Did u check whatever in the selectedRoom is actually changed and maybe the UI of the main view is not updating?

Comment: @Andreas777 Yes checked and confirmed. The value is actually changed.

Comment: @user20935301 Then I think is a problem then that is not updating the UI for some reason.
Maybe that room object is not set as ObservedObject or something.
Is also kinda new knowledge for me also, so is hard to figure it out.
But you can [check also this](https://purple.telstra.com/blog/swiftui---state-vs--stateobject-vs--observedobject-vs--environme) if these are set correctly to force the UI to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to infer the issues you encountered from your description. However I tried to create my View in the way you wrote and have successfully updated the selectedRoom as below. You can refer to my example to identify the differences.

(In this example, I used `List(1...5, id: \.self) { room in }` for simplicity and clarity. Feel free to replace it with more complex objects as needed.)

```
import SwiftUI

class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showEditRoom = false
    @Published var selectedRoom = 0
}

struct EditRoomView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var selectedRoom: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("selectedRoom: \(selectedRoom)")
        Button {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } label: {
            Text("Back")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: SomeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(1...5, id: \.self) { room in
                Text("This is room: \(room)")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.selectedRoom = room
                        viewModel.showEditRoom = true
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.showEditRoom) {
            EditRoomView(selectedRoom: $viewModel.selectedRoom)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: SomeViewModel())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implementation:

```
    struct Place: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {  
    
    let places = [Place(name: "Denver"), Place(name: "Houston")]
    @State private var selectedPlace: Place?
      
    var body: some View {
        List(places, id: \.self, selection: $selectedPlace) { place in
            Text(place.name)
        }.fullScreenCover(item: $selectedPlace) { place in
            Text(place.name)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```