# SwiftUI Sheet View Brings Wrong Data at First Time

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem when I load the `NormDetailView` of my app. It loads the default norm always instead of the selected norm by user, but after loading default one, it loads the norm selected by user.

Before that I was using `NavigationLink` and it was working perfectly how I wanted. I'm adding the code that I was using without `Sheet` for example:

```
VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(normsSearch) {norm in
                Section(header: Text(norm.title)) {
                    ForEach(norm.elements) { element in
                        NavigationLink(destination: NormDetailView(chosenNormElement: element)) {
                            Text(element.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I know that it's always loading the default norm for the first time because I checked it with using `breakpoint`. I couldn't find any solutions and I want your help. I'm putting the codes that I'm using now below for your inspection. Thanks for any help in advance

```
//The bool that I used to control the NormDetailsView
@State var showingSheet = false

//I need to create this one to use at .sheet part
@State var chosenElement: NormElements = en103052

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(normsSearch) {norm in
                    Section(header: Text(norm.title)) {
                        ForEach(norm.elements) { element in
                            Button(element.name) {
                                //I added this to pass "element" value to "chosenElement" that I created above
                                chosenElement = element
                                showingSheet.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet, content: {
                //I need to attach a chosenNormElement because I'm getting the file name from the button that clicked by user to open PDF file
                NormDetailsView(chosenNormElement: chosenElement)
            })
```

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jnpdx, I used `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)` and now my code is working. I would like to share my codes to how I solved my problem.

First, i changed `chosenElement`, I made it optional and made it equal to nil:

```
@State var chosenElement: NormElements? = nil
```

Then I changed to `sheet(item:)` down below:

```
.sheet(item: $chosenElement, content: { sheet in 
   SheetView(chosenNormElement: sheet)
})
```

That's how I solved my problem, thank you all and have a nice day