# Property not holding its value

Tags: swiftui

I have following code:

```swift
struct PostView: View {
    @State private var showAttachmentSheet = false
    @State private var attachmentID: Int = 0
    
    var currentPost: Post?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(firstPost.postscontents.reversed(), id:\.id) { post in
            Text(post.contents)

            if post.attachment.count > 0 {
                ForEach(post.attachment, id: \.id) { file in
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            attachmentID = file.id
                            debugPrint(attachmentID)
                            showAttachmentSheet = true
                        } label: {
                            TextAndImageCell(title: file.filename, imageName: "paperclip")
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        .background(.gray)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.inset)
        .listItemTint(.lightBlue)
    
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAttachmentSheet) {
            AttachmentView(attachmentID: attachmentID, ticketID: currentPost!.id)
        }

        Button {
            showSheet = true
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.message.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .padding()
        }
}
```

My problem is that attachmentID is not holding the value. I know that attachmentID is set during loop in ForEach, but when I the sheet appears, it's value is 0.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` or `.sheet(isPresented: $showAttachmentSheet) { [attachmentID] in`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162319/560942

Comment: Unrelated notes: `attachment` is supposed to be named `attachments`, `id:\.id` can be omitted  as well as `if post.attachment.count > 0 {` – the loop will be skipped if the array is empty – and more efficient than `.count > 0` for strings and collection types is `.!isEmpty`.

Comment: @jnpdx would you mind to make your comment as an answer to let me accept it?