# Dictionary data does not load in SwiftUI List when list item is selected for detail view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

A custom class in my project contains a `Dictionary` of type `[String: Double]` and uses SwiftData for storing and manipulating data. In a view, a SwiftUI `List` contains a number of objects of this class.

When I initially tap on any of the list's items to view details of the item, the detail view doesn't show the contents of the dictionary in the tapped item. However, when I come back to the list to tap another item, the contents of the dictionary in that item does show up. Then when I tap the initially tapped item again, the contents of the dictionary can show up this time around.

The suspected cause of this issue can be the latency in reading the data from the underlying database. While I can work around that by preloading the data of the dictionary in the view containing the list in the `.onTapGesture()` modifier and pass the dictionary as a parameter to the detail view for show, that would make the code look less neat and should be unnecessary. Is there a better alternative way of doing that?

The source code is as follows:

```
// TilesApp.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct TilesApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Tile.self
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TilesView(selectedTile: Tile(name: "Sample Tile", tileType: "Wall", tilePattern: ["Mosaic", 3.6]))
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


// Tile.swift
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
final class Tile {
    @Attribute (.unique) var name: String
    var tileType: String
    var tilePattern: [String: Double]

    init(name: String, type: String, tilePattern: [String: Double]) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.tilePattern = tilePattern
    }
}

// TilesView.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TilesView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Tile.name, comparator: .localized)]) private var tiles: [Tile]
    @State var selectedTile: Tile
    @State private var isShowingTileDetail = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(tiles) { tile in
                    VStack {
                         Text("\(tile.name)")
                                .bold()
                         Text("\(tile.tileType)")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                     }
                     .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedTile = tile
                        self.isShowingTileDetail = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingTileDetail, content: {
        TileDetailView(selectedTile: selectedTile, isShowingTileDetail: $isShowingTileDetail)
    }) 
}

// TileDetailView.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TileDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Bindable var selectedTile: Tile
    @Binding var isShowingTileDetail: Bool
    
    let orderedKeys = ["Mosaic", "Straw", "Dotted", "Squared", "Diamond"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap to change attending hours or swipe left to delete")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .font(.title2)
        List {
                ForEach(orderedKeys, id: \.self) { key in
                    if let value = selectedTile.tilePattern[key] {
                        Text("\(key): \(value, specifier: "%.1f")")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to (should not) show all of your code, just show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Without it it is difficult/impossible to help you.

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)` or use `.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingTileDetail, content: { [selectedTile] in`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162319/560942

Comment: You should at least make the effort to post code that compiles and runs

Comment: Thanks, @jnpdx. The `.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingTileDetail, content: { [selectedTile] in  }' approach suggested by you actually worked! I'll continue to try out editing the passed in `item` in the `EditTileView` whose code is not yet written to see whether the changes made to the passed in `item` will be communicated back to the `item` in the tiles array that is selected. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the linked answer if it was helpful.